# How do you translate an image with Symfony and Twig

Tags: image, symfony, twig, translation, translate

i am using Symfony for translate my Twig-templates. Everything is working fine but i need to set other images when a user change the language. How do i do that with Symfony and Twig?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `locale` variable from Twig using `app.request.getLocale()` and use it like:

```
# template
{% locale = app.request.getLocale(); %}
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/' ~ locale ~ '/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

Or you can try storing path to your images like regular translation resources:

```
# messages.en.yml
image.example: @AppBundle/Resources/public/images/en/example.jpg

# template
{% image 'image.example'|trans %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

Comment: If i try storing the path like regular translation i get this error:
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "|".
I use xlf for translations.

Comment: this works fine:

<img src="{{ asset('/bundles/bundleName/folder/'  ~ app.request.getLocale() ~ '/example.jpg') }}" alt="example" />

Thanks